# ASP.NET AJAX w/ Adjustable Timer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, timer

I have a quick and simple implementation:  a ListView inside an updatepanel.  To make the panel autorefresh, I added a timer:

And then added the trigger to the panel:

This works just fine.  What I'd like to do is have a dropdown with a few values (None, 5, 10, 15, 30 seconds) so the user can adjust how frequently the timer fires.  Also, it kind of implicitly lets the user know the page refreshes.

I was wondering if there was an easy way do this?  I was thinking I could add a select box/dropdown with those values, fire an event when it changes, and update the Timer's interval via javascript.  Not too sure if that's feasible.

Alternatively, I could do it serverside, but I think client side is a bit cleaner.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this blog post http://devarchive.net/client-side-timer-control-asp-net-ajax.aspx it is possible to set the tick interval clientside.  A few weeks back I tried to tap into another event handler mentioned in this post, add_tick but wasn't successful.  My issue may have been with the version of ASP.NET ajax I was using.   Either way give it a try and if it works for you then good times.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll fiddle around with it and see what I can do.  Worst case I have it server side but would be nice to stay client side.